# Easiest way to create a WebRequestString

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm sure I saw a class the other day to create a string for a WebRequest but I cannot find it now...

So Far I have:

```
private string httpRequest
        {
            get { return "http://www.AWebSite.com"; }
        }

    private string _requestString;
    public string RequestString
    {
        get { return _requestString; }
        set { _requestString = value; }
    }

    public Request()
    {
        RequestString = httpRequest;
    }

    private void UpdateRequestString(MyObj myObject)
    {
        RequestString= string.Format("{0}&someParameters={1},{2}", RequestString, myObject.first, myObject.second);
    }
```

This obviously works fine. But I'm sure I saw an easier way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you want to generate a HttpWebRequest using [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: no I don't want to create the actual webRequest. I was just wondering whether there was a class to dynamically build  the string which is then fed into the WebRequest.Create method

Comment: I guess my way is the best way